# Pack expansion in class derivation list: Is it legal?

Tags: c++

I discovered that the code below compiles in gcc and clang. 
As the `MakeDerivativeOf` template is quite useful in my current project, 
I'd like to be sure that this is indeed a real, buletproof, standard-conforming C++.
Here is the code:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename... Ts>
struct MakeDerivativeOf: private Ts...
{
};

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};


int main()
{
  using MyStruct = MakeDerivativeOf<A,B,C>;
  MyStruct obj; 
  constexpr auto value = std::is_base_of<A,MyStruct>::value 
                         && std::is_base_of<B,MyStruct>::value
                         && std::is_base_of<C,MyStruct>::value;
  static_assert(value,"assertion failed");
}
```

Comment: Why not? I don't understand why you would like to make an exception for that particular case!

Comment: @Phil1970 It just seems different than `usual' uses inside e.g. function parameter list. For instance, here we have private/public inheritance specifier. But I certainly hope it is legal!